# Failed to download Chromium r579032

Tags: vue.js, chromium, puppeteer

I am trying to build a vue project with prerendering. it relies on prerender-spa-plugin but this plugin relies on puppeteer. so when I install prerender-spa-plugin, it always show the same error 'Failed to download Chromium r579032'

```js
ERROR: Failed to download Chromium r579032! Set "PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD" env variableto skip download.
{ Error: read ETIMEDOUT
    at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:628:25) code: 'ETIMEDOUT', errno: 'ETIMEDOUT', syscall: 'read' }
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! puppeteer@1.7.0 install: `node install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the puppeteer@1.7.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/anne/.npm/_logs/2018-08-28T11_59_47_508Z-debug.log
```

I tried **npm install puppeteer --unsafe-perm=true**

it didn't work.
please let me know if you know how to solve it.

Answer (score 10):

Try the below instead:

```
sudo npm install -g puppeteer --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
```

Comment: Still get 'Error: unable to get local issuer certificate'

Answer (score 4):

Set npm mirror

```
npm config set puppeteer_download_host=https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors
npm i puppeteer
```

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1597#issuecomment-351945645

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a corporate proxy issue. Confirm that there is no firewall blocks on your network. Then ask your IT colleagues about the appropriate proxy settings if it is allowed.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I have VPN and I finally got the plugin but I gave up to use prerender way , I decided to use ssr now.

Comment: certificate issue on the server's side. company is correctly identifying and blocking a security concern

Answer (score 2):

My current work-around is to manually download Chromium with the specific version above. Then I add its install path to my environment path variable. Then use the below so puppeteer finds it.

Either with

```
PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD
```

environment variable set, or

```
npm install --ignore-scripts puppeteer
```

```
  this.loading = puppeteer.launch({ args: [ '--no-sandbox', '--full-memory-crash-report' ] }).then(aBrowser => {
    this.browser = aBrowser;
    this.loading = undefined;
    return this.browser;
  }).catch(() => {
    return puppeteer.launch({ executablePath: "chromium.exe",
                              args: [ '--no-sandbox', '--full-memory-crash-report' ] }).then(aBrowser => {
      this.browser = aBrowser;
      this.loading = undefined;
      return this.browser;
    });
  })
```

I am avoiding any download location I do not trust

Comment: You can also switch to playwright. It supports multiple browsers and isn't locked into any specific version of chromium -- but does require a little bit of migrating syntax

Answer (score 0):

my colleague gave a way use a npm mirror in China solved the problem.
`ssh
cnpm install prerender-spa-plugin@2.1.0 --save`